# How add video from app to collection?

Tags: windows-phone-7

My app downloads video from server and saves it in IsolatedStorage. 
        Can i add this video to phone collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible in Windows Phone 7. You can use MediaLibrary that will give you access to metadata related to existing songs and pictures, but that's about it. You cannot currently read or write videos stored on the phone.